# Building a json with sub array in oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have a query that returns name and list of pictures (1 or more)
The query is :

```
select id, name, last, image_path from pictutes;
```

I need to return it as json. example:

```
{
 [
   {"id":"025446578", 
    "name":"Jhon",
    "last":"torj"
    "images":[
                "0":"img_path1"
                "1":"img_path2"
        ]
   }
 ]
 [
   {"id":"54687213", 
    "name":"Aln",
    "last":"tossrj"
    "images":[
                "0":"img_path4"
        ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I have put two arrays,
but could be I only need one for the images ?
I'm not so sure about how it should be formatted.

Comment: Your JSON output is invalid as the outer object contains no keys and the `images` arrays should not contain key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, use the built-in JSON functions and group the image paths by the other columns:

```sql
SELECT JSON_SERIALIZE(
         JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'data' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
             JSON_OBJECT(
               KEY 'id'     VALUE id,
               KEY 'name'   VALUE name,
               KEY 'last'   VALUE last, 
               KEY 'images' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(image_path RETURNING CLOB)
             )
           )
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
         PRETTY
       ) AS json
FROM   pictutes
GROUP BY id, name, last;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pictutes (id, name, last, image_path) AS
  SELECT '025446578', 'Jhon', 'torj',   'img_path1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '025446578', 'Jhon', 'torj',   'img_path2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '54687213',  'Aln',  'tossrj', 'img_path4' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| JSON |
| --- |
| { "data" : [ { "id" : "54687213", "name" : "Aln", "last" : "tossrj", "images" : [ "img_path4" ] }, { "id" : "025446578", "name" : "Jhon", "last" : "torj", "images" : [ "img_path1", "img_path2" ] } ] } |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fmwByOta)